# how i can send the snapshots of failure testcases in the jenkins email attachment

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e89F2.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e89F2.png)I am using the maven project for the automation, I want to take the snapshot of failed test cases and send in the attachment, the snapshot is captured and save successfully but in Jenkins attachment is not working can anyone find out the problem?
 I am using the maven project and Jenkins 
[image]captureing of image code is working correctly and snapshot saved successfully but in Jenkins attachment, snapshots are not sent in the email

```
enter code here  public static void captureScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotname) throws Exception {
    String timeStamp;
    File screenShotName;
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    //The below method will save the screen shot in d drive with name "screenshot.png"
    timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); 
    //screenShotName = new File("D:\\MyTest\\Screenshots\\"+timeStamp+".png");
    screenShotName = new File("D:\\Automation\\EclipseWorkSpace\\WebDriverTest1\\target\\snapshot\\"+timeStamp+".png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, screenShotName);

    String filePath = screenShotName.toString();
    //String path = "<img src="\"file://"" alt="\"\"/" />";
    String path = "<img src=\"file://" + filePath + "\" alt=\"\"/>";
    Reporter.log(path);

    }
```

Comment: best way to accomplish this is . First make your screen shots taken into specific folder in your project for example if you project is A then create a folder called screenshot under that project and make the screen shots saved there. Second you need to use archive plugin to archive the folder after the build is done . third you can use attachement and attach the screen shots inside that folder to send it in the email. If yo need me to show me a little more explanation let me know. good luck

Comment: thanks for your feedback , First of all i am saving the screen shots in the specfic folder of my project directory , secondly how i can use the  archive plugin ? can you help me out ?

Comment: Build Artifacts folder is creating in the jenjkins workspace but how i can send this folder in the attachment ?

Comment: captured images are showing in the build artifacts folders but i do not know how i can send in the attachment ?

Comment: The problem is that in jenkins attachment i am using the  Pre-send Script         def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html")
  msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html"); if i am send email with this script then in attachment , screenshots is not attached in the attachment but when i tries to send attachment without the pre send script then attachment is working correctly , can u help me out how i can send attachment with the presend script

Answer (score 0):

Rather storing the screenshot in "D:\Automation\XXX" you should specify a folder relative to the project dir. The hard coded path does not work if Jenkins machine doesn't have the "D:" drive.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer , jenkin mechine is installed in the c drive , but how i can store the snapshot on the project dir ?